# Convert UTC value in dd-mm-yyyy format using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I want to convert **UTC time** value (e.g.1367214805) to date (in **dd-mm-yyyy**) format using javascript.

For e.g. in PHP if we use...

```
<?php Date("d-m-Y",'1367214805'); ?>
```

... we directly get the date in dd-mm-yyyy format.

Is there any such function in **javascript**? 
- I tried Date() in various ways in javascript but every time it is printing the present date and time!!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript uses millisecond epoch, so you need to multiply your number by 1000.

```
var t = 1367214805;
var d = new Date(t * 1000);
```

There are then `.getUTCxxx` methods to get the fields you want,  and then you can just zero pad and concatenate to get the required string.

```
function epochToDate(t) {
    function pad2(n) {
        return n > 9 ? n : '0' + n;
    }
    var d = new Date(t * 1000);
    var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;  // months start at zero
    var day = d.getUTCDate();

    return pad2(day) + '-' + pad2(month) + '-' + year;
}
```

Comment: i want to get "date" and not day!! rest both things are working fine..Thanks

Comment: @BhaumikKothari yeah, I already fixed that before you commented.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method and just ignore everything after the `T` e.g.

```
var isoDateStr = myDate.toISOString();
isoDateStr = isoDateStr.substring(0, isoDateStr.indexOf('T'));
```

This would give you standard UTC date format **yyyy-mm-dd**. If you need to specifically format the date as **dd-mm-yyyy** then you can take that result and switch the values i.e.

```
isoDateStr = isoDateStr.split('-').reverse().join('-');
```

Comment: ISO8601 is `yyyy-mm-dd`, not `dd-mm-yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/), you should be able to get whatever format you want and easily.

```
console.log(new Date());
console.log(moment().format("D-M-YY"));
console.log(moment(1367214805 * 1000).format("DD-MM-YY"));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Lb8cx/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `getUTCxxx()` methods?

```
function formatUTC(time_UTC_in_milliseconds_since_epoch) {
    /*
     * author: WesternGun
     */
    var time = new Date(time_UTC_in_milliseconds_since_epoch);
    var formatted = time.getUTCFullYear() + "-" 
        + (time.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" 
        + time.getUTCDate() + " " 
        + time.getUTCHours() + ":" 
        + time.getUTCMinutes() + ":" 
        + time.getUTCSeconds();
    return formatted;
}
```

Remember to add 1 to the month because the range of return value of `getUTCMonth()` is `0~11`.

With your input, we have:

```
formatUTC(1367214805 * 1000); // return "2013-4-29 5:53:25"
```

To format the numbers into `\d\d` form, just create another function:

```
function normalizeNumber(input, toAdd) {
    if (parseInt(input) < 10) {
        return toAdd + input;
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```

And use it like `normalizeNumber((time.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString(), "0")`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
myDate.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('-')
```